# Keep Mouse Within Circle

Tags: mouse

This is a somewhat random question. I would like to be able to keep my mouse within a circle (or square) for a period of time.

To clarify, I would like the mouse to operate as though it is within a smaller screen within the border screen. It will still be operated by the user, but will simply not move beyond the smaller area. It will still be able to interact with the activated application underneath it. It will just not be able to move past the small area.

For example:

1. Set up terminal with a command to run a script or something
2. Move mouse to a particular spot
3. Run terminal command by hitting enter
4. Now mouse will only move within a particular radius of the point it was on
5. To stop the behaviour, I guess I would have to right-click the mouse or double-click, or keyboard across to the terminal and run something else.

Is this something that could be done with xdotool or something like that?

Comment: This can be automated with Python or similar - though your requirements are a bit vague. I'm assuming you want the mouse to randomly move (so not jump) around within the shape?

Comment: I've tried to clarify

Comment: Take a look at this [script](https://pastebin.com/SuQrcSx0) posted by pfanne on [LinuxQuestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org) - [Confine mouse movement](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/confine-mouse-movement-mouse-jail-729654/#post3650849).  It is basically a set of if thens using xdotool to keep the mouse in a bounding rectangle.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Perfect. Thanks

Comment: @J.Starnes I recommend that you write up a full answer based on [your comment.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958540/keep-mouse-within-circle#comment1531988_958540)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those using Wayland, this type of fake input was explicitly excluded from Wayland's design for security. See [@grawity's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1032426) to [Wayland alternative for xorg's xdotool](https://superuser.com/questions/1032270/wayland-alternative-for-xorgs-xdotool) for a discussion of a related issue.

The script below demonstrates constraining the mouse to the window it was over when the script was started. Changing the test in the `while` command to test if a task has been completed would improve the script significantly. Uncommenting the sleep command would allow the task to be outside the original window as a skill test/puzzle.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
###
#a script to demonstrate using xdotool to restrict mouse movement to a single window. Inspired by a script posted by pfanne on LinuxQuestions.org

###

            #original mouselocation
            POS=$(xdotool getmouselocation | sed 's/:/ /g')
            WINDOW=$(echo $POS | cut -d' ' -f8)
            XPOS=$(echo $POS | cut -d' ' -f2)
            YPOS=$(echo $POS | cut -d' ' -f4)
while [ true ]
do
    if [ $WINDOW != $(xdotool getmouselocation | sed 's/:/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f8 ) ];
        then
            xdotool mousemove $XPOS $YPOS;
            #sleep 1
    fi
done
```

This script by pfanne demonstrates using an arbitrary rectangle to constrain the mouses location.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

borderxl=$1
borderyu=$2

borderxr=$3
borderyd=$4

check=0

if [ $borderxl -gt $borderxr ]
then
        check=1
fi

if [ $borderyu -gt $borderyd ]
then
        check=1
fi
if [ $check -ge "1" ]
then
        echo "Make sure the first coordinate pair refers to the upper left corner"
        echo "and the second pair refers to the lower right one."
fi

if [ $check -lt "1" ]
then
        while [ true ]
    do
            check=0
            declare -a pos
            pos=$(xdotool getmouselocation)
            #xpos=`xdotool getmouselocation | awk '{ print $1}'`
            #xpos=${xpos:2}
            #xpos=`getcurpos | awk '{ print $1}'`
            #ypos=`xdotool getmouselocation | awk '{ print $2}'`
            #ypos=${ypos:2}
            #ypos=`getcurpos | awk '{ print $2}'`

            if [ $xpos -gt $borderxr ]
            then
                    check=1
                    xpos=$borderxr
            fi

            if [ $ypos -gt $borderyd ]
            then
                    check=1
                    ypos=$borderyd
            fi

            if [ $xpos -lt $borderxl ]
            then
                    check=1
                    xpos=$borderxl
            fi

            if [ $ypos -lt $borderyu ]
            then
                    check=1
                    ypos=$borderyu
            fi


            if [ $check -ge "1" ]
            then
                    xdotool mousemove $xpos $ypos
            fi
    done   
fi
```