# How can I limit mouse pointer movement to only horizontal or only vertical?

Tags: mouse, configuration, mouse-pointer

I would like to be able to move the mouse pointer in a perfectly straight line. I am looking for a way to use two modifier key combinations, one of them making the mouse pointer move only horizontally, while moving vertically in just the normal way. It would be like I move the mouse itself only along a vertical ruler, with the mouse oriented perfectly parallel to the ruler. And the same feature for horizontal movement only, using different modifier keys, or key sequences.

I am interested in partial solutions for this too, like a command line program to limit the movement, or a different way to change the movement mode with the keyboard. Or even some kind of local "configuration hack".

A god example for the use of this feature is to allow to use the thumbnail bar in a YouTube video without the need to keep the mouse inside the horizontal range manually.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958540/keep-mouse-within-circle

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

get your screen resolution first and change the values in the script.

Sample Content for Vertical Movement, Change the value 768 with your screen vertical resolution.

```
borderxl=$XPOS
borderyu=0

borderxr=$XPOS
borderyd=768
```

Sample Content for Horizontal Movement, Change the value 1366 with your screen Horizontal resolution.

```
borderxl=0
borderyu=$YPOS

borderxr=1366
borderyd=$YPOS
```

Original Script is from this Post & the Credit also goes to this Post [Keep Mouse Within Circle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958540/keep-mouse-within-circle)

Modified Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

POS=$(xdotool getmouselocation | sed 's/:/ /g')
XPOS=$(echo $POS | cut -d' ' -f2)
YPOS=$(echo $POS | cut -d' ' -f4)

borderxl=0
borderyu=$YPOS

borderxr=1366
borderyd=$YPOS

check=0

if [ $borderxl -gt $borderxr ]
then
        check=1
fi

if [ $borderyu -gt $borderyd ]
then
        check=1
fi
if [ $check -ge "1" ]
then
        echo "Make sure the first coordinate pair refers to the upper left corner"
        echo "and the second pair refers to the lower right one."
fi

if [ $check -lt "1" ]
then
        while [ true ]
        do
                check=0
                xpos=`xdotool getmouselocation | awk '{ print $1}'`
                xpos=${xpos:2}
                #xpos=`getcurpos | awk '{ print $1}'`
                ypos=`xdotool getmouselocation | awk '{ print $2}'`
                ypos=${ypos:2}
                #ypos=`getcurpos | awk '{ print $2}'`

                if [ $xpos -gt $borderxr ]
                then
                        check=1
                        xpos=$borderxr
                fi

                if [ $ypos -gt $borderyd ]
                then
                        check=1
                        ypos=$borderyd
                fi

                if [ $xpos -lt $borderxl ]
                then
                        check=1
                        xpos=$borderxl
                fi

                if [ $ypos -lt $borderyu ]
                then
                        check=1
                        ypos=$borderyu
                fi


                if [ $check -ge "1" ]
                then
                        xdotool mousemove $xpos $ypos
                fi
        done   
fi
```

Problemes with the script.

Creating shortcut keys for these two scripts, I could not find a way to kill the process, force logging out is the only way. Initially I have created shortcut keys Alt+x and Alt+y both works perfectly.. but killing the process, I could not achieve.

[image]